# Segmentation Fault (Core dumped) in c BST

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binary-search-tree

Here I have made a program for deletion in binary search tree(BST), but getting segmentation fault (core dumped) while executing, I think it's in delete function but where don't know if I remove function call for delete function then it works fine, like finding maximum element, inorder traversal, but delete won't work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct BST{
    int data;
    struct BST *left;
    struct BST *right;
};
struct BST *newNode(int data){
    struct BST *temp = (struct BST *)malloc(sizeof(struct BST));
    temp->data=data;
    temp->left=0;
    temp->right=0;
    return temp;
}
void inOrder(struct BST *root){
    if(root==0)
        return;
    inOrder(root->left);
    printf("%d",root->data);
    inOrder(root->right);
}
struct BST *findMax(struct BST *root){
    if(root==0)
        return 0;
    if(root->right!=0)
        return findMax(root->right);
    return root;
}
struct BST *dele(struct BST *root,int data){
    if(root==0)
        return 0;
    if(data<root->data)
        root->left=dele(root->left,data);
    if(data>root->data)
        root->right=dele(root->right,data);
    else{
        if(root->left && root->right)
        {
            struct BST *temp=findMax(root->left);
            root->data=temp->data;
            root->left=dele(root->left,root->data);
        }
        else{
            struct BST *temp=root;
            if(root->left==0)
                root=root->right;
            if(root->right==0)
                root=root->left;
            free(temp);
            return root;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
void main(){
    struct BST *root = (struct BST*)malloc(sizeof(struct BST));
    root=newNode(1);
    root->left=newNode(2);
    root->right=newNode(3);
    root->left->left= newNode(4);
    root->left->right=newNode(5);
    root->right->left=newNode(6);
    root->right->right=newNode(7);
    inOrder(root);
    root=dele(root,1);
    printf("\n\n");
    inOrder(root);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to trace through?

Comment: i renamed delete to dele than also same "segmentation fault"

Comment: @Joe i am unable to debug, please help if u can.

Comment: @user1314485: Why are you "unable" to debug?

Comment: because of segmentation fault, i was unable to do anything, neither it prints nor it takes input. But now the issue is solved, But thanks for your intrest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected it myself, problem in delete function in else part

```
else if(root->data==data){
        if(root->left && root->right)
        {
            struct BST *temp=findMax(root->left);
            root->data=temp->data;
            root->left=dele1(root->left,root->data);
        }
        else{
            struct BST *temp=root;
            if(root->left==0)
                root=root->right;
            else if(root->right==0)
                root=root->left;
            free(temp);
            return root;
        }
    }
```

and nodes value i entered were not representing a BST, instead representing binary tree. So, changed it too.

```
root=newNode(5);
    root->left=newNode(3);
    root->right=newNode(7);
    root->left->left= newNode(1);
    root->left->right=newNode(4);
    root->right->left=newNode(6);
    root->right->right=newNode(8);
```

the segmentation fault was recovered by

```
else if(root->right==0
```

and, @Alter we can use both 0 as well as NULL, and as you told to change

```
if (root->left==0)
        root=root->right;
    if (root->right==0)
        root=root->left;
```

which is correct but instead of second 'if' i should have used 'else if'.
But thank for your interest in my question.

Comment: `we can use both 0 as well as NUL`, there is nothing wrong with 0, but quoting the [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/null/nullor0.html): Any usage of NULL (as opposed to 0) should be considered a gentle reminder that a pointer is involved

Answer (score 5):

```
void main(){
```

please, change to:

```
int main(void) {
```

and use `NULL` instead of `0` to compare pointers

My debugger tells me:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00000000004007f0 in delete (root=0x0, data=5) at demo.c:47 47
>   if(root->right==0)

Steps for debugging (using gdb):

- Compile using `-g` flag:

  gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -W -g -o demo demo.c
- Launch gdb:

  gdb demo
- Type:

  run

Comment: @CoolGuy, sorry, your edit was rejected because I was editing, feel free to edit again

Comment: Bug is in if(root->left==0)
            root=root->right;
        if(root->right==0)
            root=root->left; but not what you told, here in second 'if' it should be 'else if', but anyway thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is

```
        if(root->left==0)
            root=root->right;
        if(root->right==0)
            root=root->left;
```

Consider the case where both `left` and `right` branches are NULL. Then the first if (tests whether `left` is NULL, which is) will assign NULL (`right`) to `root`. Then comes the next if and try to dereference a NULL pointer (`root->`).

I think the following will correct this bug

```
        if(root->left==0)
            root=root->right;
        else if(root->right==0)
            root=root->left;
```

Or: (**edited: no, it will not work without else anyway, since the new `right` can be non NULL**)

```
        if(root->left != NULL)
            root=root->left;
        if(root->right != NULL)
            root=root->right;
```

(note in this case that `left` and `right` cannot be possibly both non NULL, as this case was dealt with before, so no memory leak here).

Comment: Still I don't understand the line `root->left=delete(root->left,root->data);` (when `root->left && root->right`)

Comment: Nevermind my previous comment. Now I got it. Also I'll edit the answer to note that my second solution will not work.